# jQuery easypaginate fade not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Im using easypaginate plugin 
http://cssglobe.com/post/9801/easy-paginate-jquery-plugin-for-pagination

here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/qTwa8/1/

basically this paginate shows each list item with fadein/out which is:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('ul#items').easyPaginate({
        step:12
    });
});
```

but when set like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('ul#items').easyPaginate({
        step:20
    });
});
```

fade effect not showing? How can I show fade effect? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how this plugin should work. Look through it's code and you'll see such a condition there:

```
  if(count>step){ // You should remove this condition to have effects in your case.

   var pages = Math.floor(count/step);
   .......rest of code......
  };
```

Remove this condition and effects will work.